# How can i find the period T of a complex continuous signal

Tags: signal-processing

I'm new to this kind of `mathematics` and i came across a really complex `signal` in a course of my university

I know that this signal `x(t) = sinωt` has a period of `T = 2π` because of `ω = 2π/T` but how can i find the `period` of this one?

[image]

Comment: you mean has a period $1/T$ (not necessarily $2\pi$)

Comment: yeah but sinωτ has 2π right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T$ is said to be period of $x(t)$ if it is the minimum value satisfying $x(t) = x(t+T)$. In your case, this becomes
$$3\cos(2\pi t) + 2\cos(3\pi t + \frac{\pi}{6}) + 4\sin(4\pi t ) = 3\cos(2\pi t + 2\pi T) + 2\cos(3\pi t +3\pi T + \frac{\pi}{6}) + 4\sin(4\pi t + 4\pi T ) = $$
for all $t$. So $T$ should be chosen as the minimum number such that $2\pi T$,$3\pi T$ and $4\pi T$ are multiples of $2\pi$, which in this case would be $T=2$.

Comment: What about the `π/6` ?it does not interfere somehow in this?

Comment: @PhillAlexakis but for $T = 2$, you get $2\cos(3\pi t +3\pi T + \frac{\pi}{6}) = 2\cos(3\pi t +6\pi + \frac{\pi}{6})=2\cos(3\pi t  + \frac{\pi}{6})$

Comment: oh i see,so we don't really take it into consideration

Comment: But let me ask you something , why `3 π` is a multiple of `2 π` ? because `3` is not a multiple of `2`

Comment: i didn't say 3 is a multiple of 2, i said $2\pi T$,$3\pi T$ and $4\pi T$ are multiples of $2\pi$

Comment: So in this:   $sin(4\pi t) + sin(8\pi t) + sin(10\pi t)$ I'm searching for a minimum number such that $4\pi T , 8\pi T , 10\pi T$ are multiples of $4\pi$ ?

Comment: no such that $4\pi T,10\pi T$ are both multiples of $2\pi$. Also $T = 2$.@PhillAlexakis

Comment: For example, $sin(4\pi t) + sin(8\pi t)$, the period is $T = \frac{1}{2}$.@PhillAlexakis

Comment: $sin(4\pi t) + sin(8\pi t) + sin(10\pi t)$ , has a period of  $T=1$ ?

Comment: yep @PhillAlexakis .. this thread answered like 4 questions, lol

Comment: haha sorry i'm trying to understand the general pattern in order to be able to calculate the period of every complex continuous signal like the ones i've mentioned